# Visual Studio 2012 MSVSMON.EXE does not work

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I'm really tired of this error.

Most of the time, when I want to debug the program , I'm faced with this message.
[image]

Microsoft to offer solutions, but it is quite confusing:

1.
Make sure the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor is installed and running on the remote machine.

2.
Make sure the Remote Server Name is correct in the Name box in the Project Properties dialog box.

3.
Verify that the remote machine is accessible on the network.

please someone help and guide me because all of my projects have been suspended and i need visual studio debugging.

meanwhile, when i dc from internet, visual studio will work.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 x64, VS 2012, VB.NET

I fixed it like this:-

Create a shortcut on your desktop to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe".
Right-click shortcut and select "Properties" from the dropdown menu.
Select the "Compatibity" tab
Tick "Run this program as administrator"
Click OK

Create a shortcut on your desktop to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe".
Right-click shortcut and select "Properties" from the dropdown menu.
Select the "Compatibity" tab
Tick "Run this program as administrator"
Click OK

To start VS2012:-

1) Double-click the msvsmon shortcut icon (that you created above, to launch msvsmon)

2) Double-click the "Visual Studio 2012 Professional" shortcut icon (that you created above, to launch VS2012)

3) In VS2012, ensure standard toolbar is visible.

4) In VS2012, ensure "Solution Platforms" dropdown (on standard toolbar) is visible and set to "x86".

and ... wowee ... debug works !

Comment: Thanks for your replay ... but 2 weeks ago i transfer visual studio to vmware workstaion and work fine just as like first time. so i can not mark or point to your answer, yet . but it seems, this problem is for x64 bit OS , but not all of them. whatever thanks for your replay again and your answer seems logic.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed changing in **properties/compile/target platform** to **x86** instead of **Any CPU**. It was the problem in my case. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when starting VS2012 as a normal user. When starting as an administrator it opened up a UserControl TestContainer window instead.

What have happend was that the startup project was changed. I changed back to my ordinary startup project by right-click on it and choose "Set as StartUp Project".

Answer (score 0):

I have started vs 2012 as administrator and it is fixed